# How to get all the words in a string starting with '{' and ending with '}' in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am new to regexs.
I have this :

```
  '@time-transform{
     [bg:red;c:white]
     [bg:black]
     [bg:white;c:black]
   }'
```

I want the part inside curly brackets.

Comment: You can match the regular expression `/(?<=\{).*?(?=\})/s`, where `/s` denotes *single-line* or *DOTALL* mode, causing a dot to match all characters, including line terminators. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TlqZn8/1)

Comment: Your title is inaccurate, as it's not *words* within a `{...}` block that you want; you evidently want the [whole enchilada](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20whole%20enchilada#:~:text=Definition%20of%20the%20whole%20enchilada,the%20whole%20enchilada%20this%20year.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can split the string by regex:

```js
const result = input.split(/({|})/)[2];
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems it can be also done without regex tho.

```
const text = '@time-transform{[bg:red;c:white][bg:black][bg:white;c:black]}';

const result = text.substring(text.indexOf('{') + 1, text.indexOf('}'));

console.log(result);
// logged: '[bg:red;c:white][bg:black][bg:white;c:black]' (string)
```